# How to merge pandas dataframe with different column but similar data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframe namely df1 and df2. I tried using outer and inner joins. The outer join have duplicates while inner join removes duplicates.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['c', 6]],
                      columns=['A', 'B'])

    A   B
0   a   2
1   b   4
2   c   6
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 2, 1], ['b', 4, 5], ['d', 6, 7]],
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    A   B   C
0   a   2   1
1   b   4   5
2   d   8   7
```

The expected output is as

```
    A   B   C
0   a   2   1.0
1   b   4   5.0
2   c   6   NaN
3   d   8   7.0
```

Comment: Did you try `how='left'`? (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @coldspeed `how = left` doesn't help. It leaves `d` row

Comment: Ah, nvm, `df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['A', 'B'])` is what you should have tried

Comment: `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')` should help.